# How to pass an object method to an array method in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

This is my first stab at OOP, so please bear with me:

```
(function(){

  var Ship = function(){
    this.passengers = [];
    this.hasAliens = function() {
      return this.passengers.some(function(passenger){
         return passenger.isAlien()
      });
    }        
  }; 

  var Passenger = function(){};
  Passenger.prototype.isAlien = function(){
    return this instanceof Alien;
  };
  Passenger.prototype.board = function(ship) {
    ship.passengers.push(this)
  }

  var Alien = function() { Passenger.call(this); }
  var Human = function() { Passenger.call(this); }
  Alien.prototype = Object.create(Passenger.prototype);
  Human.prototype = Object.create(Passenger.prototype);
  Alien.prototype.constructor = Alien.constructor;   
  Human.prototype.constructor = Human.constructor;  

  var ship = new Ship();   
  var john = new Human();
  var zorg = new Alien();

  //simple testing
  john.board(ship);
  console.log("Ship does not have aliens ", ship.hasAliens()===false);
  zorg.board(ship);
  console.log("Ship has aliens ", ship.hasAliens()===true);

})();
```

​

This works fine. However, I'd like to know how to pass the `Passenger.isAlien()` method to save me that nasty nested anonymous function. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
  var Ship = function(){
    this.passengers = [];
    this.hasAliens = function(){
      return this.passengers.some(Passenger.isAlien);          
    };
  };
```

But that gives me `"undefined is not a function"`

http://jsfiddle.net/WYyxY/

Comment: There are some flaws in your code. E.g. `Alien.prototype = Object.create(Passenger);` should be `Alien.prototype = Object.create(Passenger.prototype);` and instead of assigning the functions inside the `Passenger` constructor, you should assign them to `Passenger.prototype`. Regarding your question: You get the error because `isAlien` is a property of an *instance* of the constructor function, not the constructor function itself. There is not really a more concise way to do this than using an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, `isAlien` is a property of the prototype, i.e. an *instance* of the constructor function, and not the constructor function itself. `Passenger.isAlien` is indeed undefined (nowhere in your code is `Passenger.isAlien = function....`).

There is not really a more concise way to do this. Think about what a callback passed to `.some` is doing: It has to take an element of the array as argument and then do something with it. In your case you want to execute a method of that element.

One way to call a method and pass the object it should be called on as parameter is to use [`.call` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). Unfortunately, as with all functions in JavaScript, you cannot just get a reference to `Passenger.prototype.isAlien.call`, because `.call` looses its context (it does not know which function it refers to). You'd have to bind it to `Passenger.prototype.isAlien` first

```
this.passengers.some(
    Passenger.prototype.isAlien.call.bind(Passenger.prototype.isAlien)    
);
```

and personally I find that not more readable.

Stick with the anonymous function, your intend is much clearer. Or if you want to, you can let another function create that function:

```
function callOn(funcName) {
    return function(obj) {
        return obj[funcName]();
    };
}

this.passengers.some(callOn('isAlien'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've refactored the code. What do you think about a top level `isAlien = function(passenger){...}` and then that would allow `return this.passengers.some(isAlien);` and `Passenger.prototype.isAlien = isAlien;`

Comment: `Passenger.prototype.isAlien = isAlien` would not work as you'd expect it to. `isAlien` in this case accepts an argument, so `john.isAlien()` would through an error because `passenger` is not defined in the function. It's basically the same problem, but vice versa. You'd have to call `john.isAlien(john)` which is not straightforward either.

Comment: But if you do something like `if(!alien) alien=this` then I could provide the context no? http://jsfiddle.net/WYyxY/2/. but I'm still not sure it's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

For doing OOP with javascript, I strongly recommend checking out [prototypeJS](http://prototypejs.org/). Your code becomes much more readable, and it also supports inheritance!

Here's a [quick look](http://prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance.html) at it

Comment: Thanks indieman, I'm aware of some libraries that could help me with this, but I'd like to try it out with straight js.

Comment: Inheritance is natively supported by JavaScript. Just sayin' because you make it sound like it does not.